# I want to change a word in a windows DOC using win32ole in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm new in Ruby.Everyday I'm doing small programs in order to grasp the idea of the language. I'm trying to create a function that receives a filename and a string that will replace a specific word in the document referenced by the filename. I get an error saying that win32ole can't be loaded:

```
`require': no such file to load -- win32ole (LoadError)
```

Comment: Still trying to work it out...

Comment: What is the output of `ruby -v`? What version of Windows? Are you actually on a Mac?

Comment: @Linuxios: the output is : ruby 1.8.7 (2011-12-28 patchlevel 357) [universal-darwin11.0] I am using lion os.

Answer (score 1):

`win32ole` will only load on a Windows Machine. You cannot use this library on a Mac. It will work if you install Ruby on a Windows Virtual Machine and run your program from there.

The easiest way to do this is through the [Ruby Installer for windows](http://rubyinstaller.org).

Comment: Thanks for reply. but still, can I make a ruby code from a mac that opens a WORD document and change data? I can do it with a TXT file but having trouble still with WORD docs. THanks

Comment: I am not aware of any way to do this on a non-windows machine.